# Группа в контакте несколько раз генерирует одни и те же запросы!

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Написал чат бота и после того как ему задаёшь вопрос он отвечает но постоянно повторяет сообщение после отправки. Потом отключил его, но сегодня посмотрел запросы и увидел что даже когда робот не подключен группа генерирует запросы на которые бот должен был бы среагировать. Я уже голову сломал чтобы понять в чём проблема и где ошибка в коде бота или в настройках сообщества! Подскажи пожалуйста может вместе сможем найти ответ.

Вот такие запросы генерирует сообщество
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот часть кода бота Если вдруг ошибка там.

```
$rand = mt_rand(0000000000, 9999999999);

//Функции
function vk_send($method, $request) {

    $get_params = http_build_query($request);
    json_decode(file_get_contents(VK_API_ENDPOINT.$method.$get_params.'&access_token='.VK_API_TOKEN.'&v='.VK_API_VERSION));

}

function vk_print($user, $group_id) {

    $req = VK_API_ENDPOINT.'messages.setActivity?user_id='.$user.'&type=typing&peer_id='.$user.'&group_id='.$group_id.'&access_token='.VK_API_TOKEN.'&v='.VK_API_VERSION;
    json_decode(file_get_contents($req));

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {

    return;

}

// Получаем и декодируем уведомление
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// Проверяем secretKey
if (strcmp($data->secret, VK_API_SECRETKEY) !== 0 && strcmp($data->type, 'confirmation') !== 0) {

    return;

}

// Используя switch проверим, что находится в поле «type» (какое событие сработало и в зависимости от этого сформируем ответ).
// Проверяем, что находится в поле "type"
switch ($data->type) {

    // Запрос для подтверждения адреса сервера (посылает ВК)
    case 'confirmation':

        // Отправляем строку для подтверждения адреса 
        echo VK_API_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN;

    break;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Поиск нужного слова в сообщении
    case 'message_new':

    $userId = $data->object->peer_id;

        if (stripos($data->object->text,'сколько') !== false && stripos($data->object->text,'семейная') !== false ||
            stripos($data->object->text,'Сколько') !== false && stripos($data->object->text,'семейная') !== false 
            ) {

            //Если сообщение не первое то не будет здороваться
            if ($data->object->conversation_message_id > 1) {

                //Задержка
                sleep(3);
                // Через messages.send используя токен сообщества отправляем ответ
                $request_params = array(

                    'random_id' => $rand,
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'message' => "Стоимость"

                );

                //Отправление сообщения
                vk_print($userId, '35320184');

                sleep(12);
                vk_send('messages.send?', $request_params);


            }else{

                // через users.get получаем данные об авторе
                $request = VK_API_ENDPOINT.'users.get?user_ids='.$userId.'&access_token='.VK_API_TOKEN.'&v='.VK_API_VERSION;
                $response = file_get_contents($request);
                $response = json_decode($response,true);

                // Вытаскиваем имя отправителя
                $user_name = $response['response'][0]['first_name'];

                //Задержка
                sleep(3);
                // Через messages.send используя токен сообщества отправляем ответ
                $request_params = array(

                    'random_id' => $rand,
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'message' => "Здравствуйте, ".$user_name.".",

                );

                //Отправление сообщения
                vk_print($userId, '35320184');
                vk_send('messages.send?', $request_params);

            }

        }elseif (stripos($data->object->text,'сколько') !== false && stripos($data->object->text,'свадебная') !== false || 
                stripos($data->object->text,'сколько') !== false && stripos($data->object->text,'свадьбы') !== false
                ) {

            if ($data->object->conversation_message_id > 1) {

                //Задержка
                sleep(3);

                // Через messages.send используя токен сообщества отправляем ответ
                $request_params = array(

                    'random_id' => $rand,
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'message' => "Стоимость",
                    'dont_parse_links' => 0,
                    'disable_mentions' => 0

                );

                //Отправление сообщения
                vk_print($userId, '35320184');
                vk_send('messages.send?', $request_params);         

            }else{

                // через users.get получаем данные об авторе
                $request = VK_API_ENDPOINT.'users.get?user_ids='.$userId.'&access_token='.VK_API_TOKEN.'&v='.VK_API_VERSION;
                $response = file_get_contents($request);
                $response = json_decode($response,true);
                // Вытаскиваем имя отправителя
                $user_name = $response['response'][0]['first_name'];

                //Задержка
                sleep(3);

                // Через messages.send используя токен сообщества отправляем ответ
                $request_params = array(

                    'random_id' => $rand,
                    'user_id' => $userId,
                    'message' => "Здравствуйте, ".$user_name.,

                );

                //Отправление сообщения
                vk_print($userId, '35320184');
                vk_send('messages.send?', $request_params);

            }

        }

        // header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
        echo 'ok';

    break;
```

Comment: Уберите `sleep` из вашего кода. И проблема должна решиться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Вроди решилась. Может знаете как тогда сделать что бы бот отвечал не мгновенно, а с задержкой как реальный человек?

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
class MessageSend
{  
    public function send ($msg, $user_id, $access_token)
    {   
        $request_params = array (
            "peer_id" => $user_id,
            "random_id" => "0",
            "message" => $msg,
            "access_token" => $access_token,
            "v" => "5.103");
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
        file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?".$get_params);
    }
}

$ms = new MessageSend();
$root = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$message = $data->message->text;

switch ($root->type) {
    case "confirmation":
        echo "000000";
        break;
                
    case "message_new":
        echo ("ok");
        switch ($message) {
            case "привет":
                sleep (2);  //Задержка
                $ms->send("Hello", "141435963", $access_token); //Отправляем сообщение
                break;
                
            case "мир":
                sleep (2); //Задержка
                $ms->send("World", "141435963", $access_token); //Отправляем сообщение
                break;
        }
        break;
        
}
```

В данном примере ВК в первую очередь получает сообщение что все "ок", а потом уже выполняет условия. Тем самым можно спокойно юзать `sleep`.